# What is the precedence order of Jupyter rich representations?

Tags: jupyter-notebook

To display a Python object in a Jupyter notebook one can define methods such as _repr_svg_, _repr_html_... That return a formatted representation of that object, as explained here.

http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config/integrating.html#rich-display

Also, as mentioned here:

https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/ipython/ipython/blob/master/examples/IPython%20Kernel/Rich%20Output.ipynb

> In general the Notebook will use the richest available representation.

However, I cannot find anywhere what is the exact order of precedence of these representations, and I am not sure it the corresponding code lives in IPython, notebook or what. Can anybody clarify this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All available representations will be computed and sent to the frontend and stored in the notebook document. Each frontend will choose its favorite from among what is available. Different frontends will have different preferences (e.g. the live notebook prefers javascript and html, whereas nbconvert -> pdf via latex prefers pdf figures). Some frontends can even be configured to have different preferences. The default display order in the notebook application is defined [here](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/blob/5.0.0/notebook/static/notebook/js/outputarea.js#L1055):

- application/javascript
- text/html
- text/markdown
- text/latex
- image/svg+xml
- image/png
- image/jpeg
- application/pdf
- text/plain

Comment: That is exactly the answer I needed :) Thanks!